# How to extract video feature data from TorchVision?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I would like to extract feature data from an input video using a pre-trained model with TorchVision. I am trying to create vector embeddings for videos uploaded in my application. I am experimenting with different models and libraries and have decided to try using TorchVision as a start. I want to use TorchVision to only extract the feature data from the network, and don't care about the predictions layer. I've written the following code as a modification to the tutorial code found here: https://pytorchvideo.org/docs/tutorial_torchhub_inference

```py
import torch
import os
import sys
import pytorchvideo
import json 
from torchvision.transforms import Compose, Lambda
from torchvision.transforms._transforms_video import (
    CenterCropVideo,
    NormalizeVideo,
)
from pytorchvideo.data.encoded_video import EncodedVideo
from pytorchvideo.transforms import (
    ApplyTransformToKey,
    ShortSideScale,
    UniformTemporalSubsample,
    UniformCropVideo
) 
from typing import Dict

# download the video and keep in your local setup

# load json previously downloaded
with open("kinetics_classnames.json", "r") as f:
    kinetics_classnames = json.load(f)

kinetics_id_to_classname = {}
for k, v in kinetics_classnames.items():
    kinetics_id_to_classname[v] = str(k).replace('"', "")

device = "cpu"

# Pick a pretrained model 
model_name = "slowfast_r50"
model = torch.hub.load("facebookresearch/pytorchvideo", model=model_name, pretrained=True)

# Set to eval mode and move to the desired device
model = model.to(device)
model = model.eval()


side_size = 256
mean = [0.45, 0.45, 0.45]
std = [0.225, 0.225, 0.225]
crop_size = 256
num_frames = 32
sampling_rate = 2
frames_per_second = 30
alpha = 4

class PackPathway(torch.nn.Module):
    """
    Transform for converting video frames as a list of tensors. 
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def forward(self, frames: torch.Tensor):
        fast_pathway = frames
        # Perform temporal sampling from the fast pathway.
        slow_pathway = torch.index_select(
            frames,
            1,
            torch.linspace(
                0, frames.shape[1] - 1, frames.shape[1] // alpha
            ).long(),
        )
        frame_list = [slow_pathway, fast_pathway]
        return frame_list

transform =  ApplyTransformToKey(
    key="video",
    transform=Compose(
        [
            UniformTemporalSubsample(num_frames),
            Lambda(lambda x: x/255.0),
            NormalizeVideo(mean, std),
            ShortSideScale(
                size=side_size
            ),
            CenterCropVideo(crop_size),
            PackPathway()
        ]
    ),
)

clip_duration = (num_frames * sampling_rate) / frames_per_second

video_path = "videos/dance-ref.mp4"

# Select the duration of the clip to load by specifying the start and end duration
# The start_sec should correspond to where the action occurs in the video
start_sec = 0
end_sec = start_sec + clip_duration 

# Initialize an EncodedVideo helper class
video = EncodedVideo.from_path(video_path)

video_data = video.get_clip(start_sec=start_sec, end_sec=end_sec)
video_data = transform(video_data)

# Move the inputs to the desired device
inputs = video_data["video"]
inputs = [i.to(device)[None, ...] for i in inputs]


# ====================================================
# ====================================================

# MY CODE STARTS HERE

# ???? Pass the input clip through the model ----> ???? IS THIS RIGHT ????
with torch.no_grad():
    features = model(inputs)

# ???? Extract the features from the model outputs ----> ???? IS THIS RIGHT ????
video_features = features[0]
print(video_features)

# Convert the features to a numpy array
video_features_numpy = video_features.cpu().numpy()

# # Save or use the extracted features as required

print("Video features shape:", video_features_numpy.shape)

# ========================================================
# ========================================================
```

I'm able to successfully run the above code with a 6s MP4 file, and get a `videos_features` tensor that looks like the following

```py
tensor([-1.9821,  2.8263,  2.1701,  1.6154,  1.1735, -0.5454,  3.1007, -1.0148,
        -3.6750,  4.2689, -4.7927, -0.0169, -0.1962, -1.4708, -1.5922,  2.6237,
         0.1084, -3.7745,  6.4788, -1.6524,  4.9284,  0.4926, -4.0563, -3.9910,
        -2.2548, -3.1320, -1.3404, -0.4476, -1.4218, -3.4924,  0.6958,  1.6900,
         0.2106, -1.3736,  2.2864, -0.3592,  2.2289,  0.1442, -1.8074, -2.4979,
        -2.3791, -0.2976, -3.2424,  1.3375,  1.6350,  3.8064, -2.2478, -3.0865,
         1.6706,  0.6029,  2.6625,  3.0596, -4.7690, -3.4432, -3.0771,  2.6418,
         0.2366,  4.1583, -1.0962, -0.4212, -0.0736, -3.0282, -4.1238, -1.9783,
        -1.3441, -0.0184, -1.1156, -0.5393, -2.2806,  4.1601, -1.6444, -0.7249,
        -3.6805, -2.0551, -1.4813,  7.5987,  1.3691, -2.4017, -3.8850, -0.3597,
         0.4439, -1.0678, -1.4456,  0.6994,  5.5218,  9.0466,  4.3888,  3.9608,
        -0.8512,  2.0209, -3.4137,  1.6769, -1.2179, -1.6568,  1.1136,  3.9531,
        -1.3606, -3.5178, -3.7164, -1.2358,  2.2800,  1.2855,  0.8849, -1.7881,
        -4.4302,  1.1764, -2.0817, -0.5712, -1.1572,  0.0537, -0.4094, -0.6918,
        -0.2513,  0.2467, -1.0180, -1.6101, -0.7718, -0.1022, -1.7227,  2.3086,
         2.0722,  0.5302,  0.7703, -3.1986, -2.3239, -1.1310, -1.6369,  4.0920,
         2.8782,  2.2141,  0.8533, -0.5665, -0.1514, -1.9630,  1.3756, -1.0860,
        -2.7590,  1.0317, -1.4258, -2.1501,  5.0960, -1.1220, -1.7123, -0.7903,
        -1.4183, -0.2087,  1.2878,  1.7105,  0.2869,  2.9050,  2.9899, -0.2728,
         4.7932, -0.7014, -1.5389, -0.1152, -0.0474,  1.4048,  3.1718,  2.2160,
        -1.6214,  0.7943, -2.5020, -3.2082,  0.8858, -1.8662, -1.1012, -2.6207,
         0.2889,  3.6911,  2.7581, -0.0571, -0.5455,  2.0639, -2.3191, -1.1087,
         4.1987, -0.8071, -1.1458,  3.1588,  2.7729, -2.8032, -1.3898,  3.0366,
        -2.0316, -1.3805, -0.1359, -1.8186, -0.2542, -0.8707, -1.9852, -1.2235,
         1.0158,  0.9162,  1.4559, -1.6343,  1.2414, -1.9392,  1.4031, -2.1087,
         1.4264, -2.4433,  1.9987,  1.7435, -1.4833, -3.1516, -1.4445, -2.1622,
        -2.2369,  0.1812, -2.8856, -1.6360, -1.2518, -0.7845, -1.7512, -2.5064,
        -0.3540,  0.3833,  1.6118, -0.4336,  2.0720,  0.6949, -1.4684,  0.9319,
        -0.9313,  1.0400, -1.0594,  2.0087,  0.4493, -0.4025,  0.4134,  0.7111,
         0.3996,  0.8774,  0.8218, -2.0119,  0.0209, -0.0683, -1.3235,  1.1631,
        -3.3529,  1.4851, -1.4377,  0.7852,  2.6475,  2.1539,  0.4691,  0.4507,
         0.7110, -0.5095,  2.3065,  1.9916, -1.3286, -1.7927,  2.4497,  1.3198,
         1.8685, -3.3018,  0.9448,  3.2290, -0.4314, -0.5258, -0.6892, -0.7341,
        -1.6591, -1.8810,  1.3341, -2.5562, -0.5884, -1.3494,  0.8167, -3.7821,
        -2.6291,  0.1978, -2.6444,  2.2419,  0.6851,  6.9734, -1.8426,  4.4381,
         3.1089, -0.4378, -2.0963, 13.2114, -2.3495, -1.4426, -1.9189,  0.2592,
         5.8859, -0.2508, -3.0295, -1.6773,  0.4791, -1.9572, -1.6253, -1.6195,
        -0.4837, -2.6122,  0.4286, -1.1611, -1.1360, -0.7268,  2.8653,  4.6620,
         3.4540,  0.7291, -0.5427, -3.7651, -2.4088, -2.4389, -4.7705,  1.6347,
        -0.4340,  1.4351,  4.2842, -3.5035,  1.0571, -1.2533, -0.7830,  0.0691,
        -0.7862, -2.1768, -2.1578, -2.7129, -4.1147,  1.8840,  2.6636, -0.6870,
        -1.2871, -1.6168,  1.1077,  0.3935,  0.7113,  3.8313,  2.6637, -2.5640,
         0.1232, -0.7430,  0.4223, -1.3614, -1.6789, -2.9733,  9.9477,  3.0220,
        -0.2637,  5.1678,  6.6713,  0.6019, 10.7924,  8.3177, -0.9295, -1.5543,
        -0.3505,  0.1688,  0.6537, -0.1640,  1.3055,  3.4136,  0.2583,  0.8225,
        -4.4612,  1.6903, -0.4007,  1.3425,  2.9813,  0.5024, -1.2420, -0.6149,
         0.2431, -0.8499, -0.8958, -1.2067, -0.8097, -1.8516, -0.7760, -1.0694,
         0.1784,  0.0654, -0.9802, -1.0626, -0.9252, -0.3014,  1.6073, -0.9973,
        -1.8135, -2.8053, -1.2856, -0.8454, -0.9315, -0.6872, -3.7964, -4.5057,
         0.8394, -1.7831, -1.5461,  3.4923,  1.0021,  1.1010,  5.0368,  6.9367])
```

However, the dimensions of this tensor seem far too low and seem to correspond to predictions for each of the Kinetics 400 categories instead. I feel like I need to find the correct layer in the model in order to see the feature data of the videos before it becomes transformed. I may not be understanding correctly, but the model being used here is `slowfast_r50` which relies on the 3d CNN Resnet50 and is described in this paper: https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2019/papers/Feichtenhofer_SlowFast_Networks_for_Video_Recognition_ICCV_2019_paper.pdf.

Am I maybe using the wrong model here? Will this model not even provide me with the features data like I'm expecting from a more standard 3D CNN? I have not been able to see any immediate references for how to access these feature layers in the PytorchVision reference docs found here: https://pytorchvideo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html. So my question is: **What can I do to print out the video feature data and not the predictions data using TorchVision?** I am also new to AI, neural networks, and even Python (coming from a JavaScript background however). So any guidance or recommendations are definitely welcome. Please let me know if you need any more clarification or if I can help you in any way.